# Código não funciona e não retorna erro (Java)

Tags: java

Sou novo no Java, e não consigo executar este código:

```
package exercicio.pkg4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x[] = new int[10];
        int i;
        int resto;

        for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Digite o %iº número\n",i);
            x[i] = ler.nextInt();
        }
        for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            resto = x[i]%2;
            if(resto == 0)
            {
                System.out.printf("%i <- numero par. ",x[i]);
            }else{
                System.out.printf("%i <- numero impar. ",x[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Aparece as seguintes mensagens na saída:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'i'
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2691)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2720)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at exercicio.pkg4.Exercicio4.main(Exercicio4.java:16)
Java Result: 1
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 1 segundo)
```

Comment: Troque `%iº` por `%dº`, resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código possui dois problemas:

- Primeiramente não existe `%i` no `Printf`, para valores do tipo `int` ou `Integer` use `%d` e é isto que está causando a `UnknownFormatConversionException` descrita na sua pergunta;
- Os arrays em Java começam em 0 o que significa dizer que o primeiro indice é 0 e o último indice é o tamnaho do array - 1, se você observar no seu código você insere o primeiro valor na posição 1 já que a variável de controle `i` é iniciada com 1 e vai até o valor 11 já que usa `i <= 10`, se não corrigido seu código disparará uma `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Logo, seu código com as correções ficaria:

```
package exercicio.pkg4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x[] = new int[10];
        int i;
        int resto;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Digite o %dº número\n", i + 1);
            x[i] = ler.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            resto = x[i] % 2;

            if (resto == 0) {
                System.out.printf("%d <- numero par. ", x[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%d <- numero impar. ", x[i]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite, use %d para decimais não %i

Comment: Bruno, tente explicar o motivo e dê exemplos nas suas respostas sempre que possível. Se não ela poderá ser considerada de baixa qualidade.